# How come I have two different user agents at the same time with PhantomJS in python?

Tags: python, phantomjs, screen-scraping, user-agent

Below code sets the user agent for a phantomJS instance, prints it, and then scrapes a website that determines it again. The results are different. How can this be? I have not yet been able to reproduce [this](https://medium.com/@rodrigoarrigoni/phantomjs-changing-navigator-values-87873385080a) apparent solution.

1) Set **ONE** user agent

```
serviceDefaults=["--ignore-ssl-errors=yes",]
desiredDefaults={
          "phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
           AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"}
```

2) Set up driver and print user agent

```
def create_phantomJS():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs.exe", desired_capabilities=desiredDefaults, service_args=serviceDefaults)
    phantom_exc_uri='/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute'
    driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', phantom_exc_uri)
    initScript="""             
    this.onInitialized=function() {
        var page=this;
        if (page.navigator == page.settings.userAgent){return};
        page.settings.navigator = page.settings.userAgent;
    }
    """
    driver.execute('executePhantomScript',{'script': initScript, 'args': []})
    agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent")
    print "rawUa:", agent
    return driver
```

3) Scrape website to determine user agent and print it

```
def use_driver(driver, URL):
    website = driver.get(URL) 
    html = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "rawUa")))
    return text
```

4) Compare results

```
driver = create_phantomJS()
text = use_driver(driver, URL)
print text
```

**The output is TWO different user agents.**

```
rawUa: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.1.1 Safari/538.1
rawUa: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

**How to match the User Agent in this scenario in python?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improving the initScrip might work.

```
initScript="""
this.onInitialized=function() {
console.log("[INFO] TESTING NAVIGATOR VALUE");
if (navigator.userAgent == this.settings.userAgent){return};
navigator={"User-Agent":this.settings.userAgent};
}.bind(this);
"""
```

The navigator must be set to a new object. The print just after the driver creation will not give the proper test result since the handler onInitialized will be called after the page creation and before the URL request.